# Where is the Primefaces 3.2 Client Side API docs?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I downloaded Primefaces 3.2 but I cant find the javadocs for the client side API.
They say it has rich client side api so I'd could take a look at it also.

Thanks.

Comment: are you asking about javascript widget api?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Everything about PrimeFaces is here

https://www.primefaces.org/documentation/

Comment: Cient side api is in user's guide and there are plans to generate them with jsdoc as well.

Comment: @MuhammadAdnan Updated links with current ones.

Answer (score 9):

Though this may sound too trivial, but as a potential work-around, if one cannot find desired property/function name in provided documentation, one can do the following:

1.Add `widgetVar` to component:

```
    <p:dataTable widgetVar="caseDataTable" ...>
        ...
    </p:dataTable>
```

2.Open corresponding page in browser with adequate developers console (I prefer `Chrome`, but `Firefox` should also do), open JS console, type name of the JS variable and `.` and console should show dropdown list of properties/functions available:

[image: Chrome console with dropdown]

3.Try to guess which property/function does what :)

Though one should use those functions/properties carefully, because since they are not documented, they may be removed in future releases etc, but as a work-around this may work.

Hope this helps...

Comment: This used to work but now no longer works now with PF 5.0 or PF 4.0 .. Any ideas about other ways to see what all methods are available via widgetvar ?

Comment: @user01 sorry, don't have the slightest idea since I'm not using PF anymore :)

Comment: @user01 With PF 4.0 and above, you have to type `PF('theWidgetVarName')` instead of just `theWidgetVarName`. @Yura should update his answer.