# Is the API for the PrimeFaces Javascript library (ie: widgetVars) available and documented?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I've been searching around for any documentation relating to the PrimeFaces widgetVars Javascript components, looking for the API and any related documentation.

I find that while the PF JSF components are well documented in the [PF docs](https://www.primefaces.org/documentation/), I can't seem to find anything relating to the Javascript widget library - how to use the widgets or manipulate them in JS.

Is there any documentation available for that?  I found a great [Intro to the WidgetVar blog by Hatem Alimam](http://blog.hatemalimam.com/intro-to-primefaces-widgetvar/), but am looking for something a little more comprehensive that covers the different widgets, methods, etc.

Is my only choice to read through the JS code itself?  The code is now [hosted on github](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces) in src/main/resources/META-INF/resources.  But I'm not even sure which file(s) to look at.

Comment: I would also like that, but it seems that they didn't create an official docs for that API... yet! It has been 6 versions and still nothing. One thing to notice is that the API is basically jquery, though the methods/functions you need to go though the code to understand. It is such a great library with this huge gap. =/

Comment: @JorgeCampos My problem is that I'm not even sure which file(s) to read in the JS code.  For instance, I'm trying to see how to select a radio button via the JS code, but don't even know in which JS file in META-INF/resources/primefaces to read!

Comment: Well, for that you can open the showcase page, go to the Inspect (F12 in Chrome), go to the Sources Tab, then go to the path `showcase -> javax.faces.resource -> component.js.xhtml?.....` here you will find all definitions for the Prime components (don't forget to click on the format code button `{}` on the bottom of the code panel). Couldn't find it on the primefaces github page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For many 'basic' components that have a direct html counterpart, you can always use the basic html api's (or their jquery counterparts), e.g. the [plain html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15839169/how-to-get-value-of-selected-radio-button) and ['PrimeFaces' counterpart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32914247/get-pselectoneradio-value-to-a-js-function) for reading the selection of a radioButton, they are identical. Could this be enhanced with more intuitive `PF('mySelectOneRadio').selected()` ?  Yes maybe... (file an enhancement request in github)

Additional functions are [documented in the documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10632879/where-is-the-primefaces-3-2-client-side-api-docs?answertab=active#tab-top), e.g. for the [selectOneRadio](https://www.primefaces.org/docs/guide/primefaces_user_guide_6_0.pdf#458) or the [selectManyMenu](https://www.primefaces.org/docs/guide/primefaces_user_guide_6_0.pdf#454).

The widgetName is also in the documentation, e.g. 'PrimeFaces.widget.SelectOneRadio', which can easily be found with a recursive grep or a decent IDE. And it turns out that 'basic' form inputs are in the 'form.js', including the [`p:selectOneRadio`](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/master/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces/forms/forms.js#L1306).

More complex non-default ui components have their api also in the documentation and have their own [.js files](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/tree/master/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces)

E.g. the [`p:dataTable` api](https://www.primefaces.org/docs/guide/primefaces_user_guide_6_0.pdf#176) and the corresponding [`PrimeFaces.widget.DataTable` javascript file](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/master/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces/datatable/datatable.js) file

Comment: Thanks.  I don't know why I missed it b/c I had downloaded the code from github and did a full regressive search but hadn't found it.  Not sure why the IDE didn't find it.

Answer (score 0):

I just created the Primefaces widgetVar Documentation (below) where I want to show how `widgetVar` works and show the main Javascript functions.

Right now there is just the Datatable, however I plan to cover all the components if it could be of any help.

Note: I'm taking all the information from the `.js` in the [GitHub Repository](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/tree/master/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces) so the informations could be a little raw.

---

[`datatable.js`](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/master/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces/datatable/datatable.js) in GitHub Reporitory

| Function| Details |
| --------- | ------- |
| `bindPaginator: function()` | Binds the change event listener and renders the paginator |

| `loadLiveRows: function()` | Loads rows on-the-fly when scrolling live |

| `paginate: function(newState)` | Ajax pagination |

| `fetchNextPage: function(newState)` | Loads next page asynchronously to keep it at viewstate and Updates viewstate |

| `sort: function(columnHeader, order, multi)` | Ajax sort |

| `filter: function()` | Ajax filter |

| `onRowClick: function(event, rowElement, silent)` | |

| `onRowDblclick: function(event, row)` | |

| `highlightRow: function(row)` | Highlights row as selected |

| `unhighlightRow: function(row)` | Clears selected visuals |

| `fireRowSelectEvent: function(rowKey, behaviorEvent)` | Sends a rowSelectEvent on server side to invoke a rowSelectListener if defined |

| `fireRowUnselectEvent: function(rowKey, behaviorEvent)`| Sends a rowUnselectEvent on server side to invoke a rowUnselectListener if defined |

| `selectRowWithRadio: function(radio)` | Selects the corresping row of a radio based column selection |

| `unselectAllRows: function()` | |

| `selectAllRowsOnPage: function()` | |

| `unselectAllRowsOnPage: function()` | |

| `selectAllRows: function()` | |

| `toggleExpansion: function(toggler)` | Expands a row to display detail content |

| `collapseRow: function(row)` | |

| `collapseAllRows: function()` | |

| `getExpandedRows: function()` | |

| `switchToRowEdit: function(row)` | |

| `showRowEditors: function(row)` | |

| `saveRowEdit: function(rowEditor)` | Saves the edited row |

| `cancelRowEdit: function(rowEditor)` | |

| `updateRow: function(row, content)` | Updates row with given content |

| `clearSelection: function()` | Clears the selection state |

| `clearFilters: function()` | Clears table filters |

| `removeSelection: function(rowIndex)` | Remove given rowIndex from selection |

| `addSelection: function(rowKey)` | Adds given rowKey to selection if it doesn't exist already |

| `isSelected: function(rowKey)` | Finds if given rowKey is in selection |

| `saveColumnOrder: function()` | |

| `isEmpty: function()` | Returns if there is any data displayed |

| `getSelectedRowsCount: function()` | |
|

Comment: Don't do this. This isn't documentation. Those are internal implementation details, not part of an API. PF's User Guide documents some widget methods - that's an API. Everything else can change or be removed without warning in the next PF version, even in a minor version. If you rely on implementation details, you're gonna have a hard time updating to new PF versions. Which means no new features, no bugfixes. You're stuck now.

Comment: Yes, don't do this... Better then to fork the source, add stuff to the jsf files that can be used to generate jsdoc... and file pull requests